# "xxx' is inaccessible due to its protection level" Everything is public (I think)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and I don't know why I get this compiler error:

> 'CountScore.ScorePlayer1' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Here is the code:

```cs
public class CountScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text Scoreboard;
    public int ScorePlayer1 = 0;
    public int ScorePlayer2 = 0;
    public GameObject ball;

    void Start()
    {
        ball = GameObject.Find("Ball");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (ball.transform.position.x >= 8.36f)
        {
            ScorePlayer1++;
        }

        if (ball.transform.position.x <= -8.36f)
        {
            ScorePlayer2++;
        }
        Scoreboard.text = ScorePlayer1.ToString() + " : " + ScorePlayer2.ToString();
    }
}
```

```
public class WinCondition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CountScore count;
        
    void Start()
    {
    count = GetComponent<CountScore>();
    }
        
    void Update()
    {
        if(count.ScorePlayer1 >= 2)
        {
            print("Player 1 wins");
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is public. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: On the error, right click and go to declaration. Maybe you have two CountScore and the other one is picked. Or you need to save the script maybe.

Comment: As Everts says ... Or the code here does not fully match the code you are actually using ... the code you show here would not create that exception except there is something you don't tell us ;)

Comment: Are there maybe any other errors in the console? In that case you'll have to fix them all first ... it's possible the block Unity from recompilation so your latest changes did not take effect yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, everything is not public. By default, everything in C# is private. When you write `void Start()`, that actually means `private void Start()`. I advice you to make it `protected` or `public`.

Comment: But the error is not about void Start(), which is called by Unity by convention and through reflection anyway.

Comment: `By default c# is private` this is not completely true. By default c# classes are internal

Comment: This answer does not fix the problem in the question and it is also not even factually accurate...